# Less and Bootstrap variables between values

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, variables, less

I have default Bootstrap variables and they work fine however I have:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
}
```

How can I also have variables for between `@screen-xs-min` and `@screen-sm-min`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `@media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-min) {..}`? If not, could you please add more details to the question?

Comment: `@screen-xs-min` is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

`@media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-min){
   ...CSS Code Here
}`

Although as a general rule it's a good idea to use max-width only for most of your CSS in Bootstrap so your style rules cascade downwards for smaller devices. So, you could use:

`@media (max-width: @screen-sm-min){
   ...CSS Code Here
}`

for tablets, and when you find that certain elements don't look right on phones override those tablet rules with:

`@media (max-width: @screen-xs-min){
   ...CSS Code Here
}`

That being said, I often find the need to use max-width and min-width together for minor tweaks, usually one or two style rules once I've gotten the responsive layout together.